# Adding multiple records to a table through a form that is required to be filled by more than one user

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

Currently I have a Form setup where a user can fill out information (textboxes), click an add button and the record gets added into my table (it gets added to a random row in the table, not sure why).

I am trying to accomplish something different.

The form has two fields that is not supposed to be filled out by user, but by somebody else (an approver). There are usually multiple records a user will submit at a time so is it possible 
to have the user fill out the form multiple times (multiple records), have them sit in a type of que until the approver inserts the final comments than proceeds to click the add button to add the record to the table?

Form code:

Option Compare Database

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()

On Error GoTo Err1
  DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
  Exit Sub
Err1:
  Description.SetFocus
  btnAddRec.Enabled = False
  MsgBox (Err.Description)

End Sub
```

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: This question is too broad in my opinion. You can adjust the form to insert records into a different table (the queue) and then have a different form where the approver can move those records from the queue to the approved records, but those details are too broad.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I felt that might be the case. I like the solution you presented I will be giving this a try right now. I will report back.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the forms for the users and approvers. Remove those two fields from the user form (and change them columns in the table to Required = No).